# Weird syscall numbers on Linux 32 bits

Tags: linux, x86, header-files, x86-64, system-calls

## The story

I have a C program which generates automatically a list of *syscall* numbers, as I prefer automated generation from real world reference than hand‑written generated files when, applicable. The target is an Ada package. I've run a test with the classical “Hello world” involving the common `write` syscall… it failed. I figured the syscall number was wrong: 64 instead of 4.

I generated the list from a C program including `<asm-generic/unistd.h>`. The platform is 32 bits and no tool‑chain targeting 64 bits platform was ever installed.

Examples definitions from this `unistd.h`: `#define __NR_write 64` (should be 4), `#define __NR_read 63` (should be 3), `#define __NR_getuid 174` (should be 24), and so on…

I've run a text search in all files in `/usr/**` for occurrences of `__NR_write` which would be part of the expected definition, and found no one.

## The question

Why this header specify weird syscall numbers? Why is the expected definitions found nowhere? Is this a new ABI?

Note: the platform is Ubuntu 12.04, 32 bits.

### Update

I figured something running this command:

```
find /usr/include/ -name "unistd*" -exec nano '{}' \;
```

It shows the header `/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/asm/unistd_32.h` contains the good numbers, and that header is included from `/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/asm/unistd.h`, but many of the symbols are not defined when `<asm/unistd.h>` is included.

### Update 2

Not only the numbers differs, but many names too. Ex. `__NR_socket` vs `__NR_socketcall`. The start of an explanation may be given in the possible duplicate: [arch/x86/include/asm/unistd.h vs. include/asm-generic/unistd.h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10988759/arch-x86-include-asm-unistd-h-vs-include-asm-generic-unistd-h).

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10988759/arch-x86-include-asm-unistd-h-vs-include-asm-generic-unistd-h

Comment: `kill -l` will get you a list of systemcall **names** (as of the state of the currently running library). For cross-compilers things will be differnt, obviously.

Comment: @wildplasser - no, that gives you a list of **signal** names, which have nothing to do with syscalls. If you want a list of syscall numbers, go look at `asm/unistd.h`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you start with */usr/include/sys/syscall.h* (as indicated in syscall(2)) and repeatedly follow the include directives you arrive at */usr/include/asm/unistd_32.h*. Hence I recommend you use this header.

Comment: I will go for this one I just noticed too. According to the topic mentioned as a possible duplicate, [asm/unistd.h vs. asm-generic/unistd.h](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10988759/arch-x86-include-asm-unistd-h-vs-include-asm-generic-unistd-h), the situation is a bit confusing due to some re‑factoring in the headers.

Answer (score 0):

From the source of `asm-generic.h`:

```
  6 /*
  7  * This file contains the system call numbers, based on the
  8  * layout of the x86-64 architecture, which embeds the
                     ^^^^^^
  9  * pointer to the syscall in the table.
 10  *
       ...
 15  */
```

Comment: I've obviously seen this (by the way, this is `asm-generic/unistd.h`, not `asm-generic.h`), but this is the only one, so I can't pick another one. The syscall numbers are not installed any‑more with the kernel headers?. Any way, the syscall numbers for 64 bits platform are not these ones neither.